# Appending value to a TextView after successful login

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a login form in my app. I want to display the message "Welcome " once the user logs in successfully. I am passing the userid as a value to the intent while moving from the login screen to home screen as shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ApplicationHomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("UserId", txtUserId.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the Home screen, I have set the TextView value to "Welcome" in the layout.xml file since "Welcome" part is a contant string for all the users. Then i am fetching the username using this code:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String userId = bundle.getString("UserId");
```

Now I want to append the userId to the TextView(containing "Welcome" in the layout.xml) and display it to the user. I am not able to find any append() method hence i am not able to append the userId to "Welcome". How to do this then? Need some help on this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do `"Welcome" + userID` This will append the user Id to welcome text

Answer (score 1):

You need to append it yourself:

```
txtUserId.setText(txtUserId.getText().toString() + appendedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define your welcome string in resources as `Welcome $1%s` and then

```
txtUserId.setText(getString(R.string.welcome, bundle.getString("UserId"));
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29